# Adding Time in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I have a list of time i am pulling from Skype's diagnostic tool, I am trying to add these numbers to get a cumulative total.

However when I add the numbers it results in `00:00:00`

The source data is displayed as hh:mm:ss, however if I remove the first H, it works, and I can add the number, but I have to remove them manually, if I do the `=right() function` I get the same issue.

```
00:00:09
00:00:22
00:03:36
00:04:56
00:06:17
00:06:45
00:07:32
00:08:02
00:08:35
00:10:39
00:11:41
00:12:46
= 00:00:00
```

Right now I can remove manually, but we start diagnostic on the company in a few days and manually removing 0' from 4000 entries isn't efficient,

Please let me know if you can help, or need further information.

P.S I have tried playing with the format of it for several days now, and I have researched this continuously, changing it to `[HH]:mm:ss` does not help.

Comment: I copied your values (as they are) from this post, did a text to column on space and got the correct sum using `=SUM(A1:L1)`. So, I cannot reproduce the problem you seem to be having. (BTW: same result now with the edited post.)

Comment: @Ralph beat me to it but with the column formatted as time then Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Finish works as well. The values are likely left-aligned. True time values are right-aligned by default and will be after text-to-columns.

Comment: You will get ***0*** if the values are **text** rather than true times.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you so much, i have been googling time conversion for over a day now, and nobody mentioned converting it text-to-column,only recommended changing format. I can confirm this works now, Thank you so much! I some reason cannot check your answer as correct.